# Can Sidekicks take the average on the Hit Die to determine the max HP increase when they level up?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-advancement, hit-points, hit-dice, sidekick

Reading through the new rules for [Sidekicks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/dungeon-masters-tools#Sidekicks) in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* (p. 142), it seems like they must roll for HP when they level up. Am I understanding this right? Or can I use *Monster Manual* rules for average?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Or can I use *Monster Manual* rules for average?" The PHB contains rules for taking the average on the hit die (rounded up) + Con mod when a character levels up, but the MM doesn't have such rules for monsters "leveling up" at all. The introduction to the MM (and the [corresponding section of the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#HitPoints)) just explains how to read statblocks (i.e. they list HP as both a die expression and an average number), and lists hit die sizes (and their average values) by creature size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There are no rules saying a sidekick can take average on Hit Dice.

Every player class in the *Player's Handbook* (and the Artificer class in both *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* and *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*) states that a player can take the average on each Hit Dice they gain when leveling up, as well as stating that the 1st level in the class is not a roll of the Hit Die, but the whole amount.

However, according to what's stated in the sidekick rules on page 142 of *TCoE*, you would need to roll for each new Hit Die the sidekick gains.

> Whenever the sidekick gains a level, it gains one Hit Die, and its hit point maximum increases. To determine the amount of the increase, roll the Hit Die (the type of die appears in the sidekick's stat block), and add its Constitution modifier. It gains a minimum of 1 hit point per level.

---

Of course, a DM could rule otherwise, allowing the sidekick to follow the rules for Hit Points average presented for monsters in the *Monster Manual* (page 7), or they could even rule that said sidekick could use the average of player classes' Hit Dice.